# Adding an animated watermark on a video

Tags: compositing-nodes, video

I'm trying to add an animated logo watermark made of looping image sequence on a 1080p video using alpha over node in the compositor, but the rendering is 2-3 seconds for each frame and that can take a lot of time for long videos. Is there another method to do that to increase the processing speed?

Comment: Is the watermark overlay image the same resolution as your video? (It should be.) Does it have color data or is it B&W? (Color data generally takes longer to calculate.) Once you've done all you can to optimize, you must accept that compositing takes time, just like rendering. Faster hardware helps, of course. You might also check to see if the process you're doing could be accomplished with ImageMagick instead, and benchmark it against Blender.

Comment: The image sequence is scaled and re-positioned to the corner of the screen and its B&W color, but I think I found a simpler solution than using the compostitor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some tests I found out that Video Sequence Editor gives 5-10 times faster result than the Compositor.

I added a Transform Strip to the Logo image sequence, changed Blend to Alpha Over and adjusted Position and Uniform Scale, then duplicated both Logo and Transform strips to match the video length.

[image]