# How to make a logo cycle (or loop) on top of a clip in movie editing mode?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I would like to create in the movie editing layout a cyclic moving logo over a video, for instance a spinning globe.

**I know how to make a static logo**:

1. check the dimensions of the movie clip
2. create an empty image with same dimensions with transparent background in gimp, add a logo and export as png file.
3. add movie clip and image with logo onto different channels in movie editing mode of Blender with the image being on top of the movie clip.
4. choose "back drop" in the properties window of the image to the right.
5. expand the image to the length of the movie-clip

**How to change the steps in order to achieve a cyclic moving l**ogo ?

Comment: Please specify, is the logo to display a 3D quality or just a label?

Comment: just label, I only have an animated image of about 20 pictures total, that I would like repeatedly play

Comment: Related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34302/adding-an-animated-watermark-on-a-video

Comment: Your images have sequential names?

Comment: i numerated them with nr1,nr2,..nr20

Comment: Are we talking about XY movement ................. or repeating a sequence of images multiple  times?  If the latter, you may want to change the words of your question ... or not.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like there is no option to make an image sequence loop in within the VSE.

A workaround is loading your image sequence in the compositor, making sure you have the cyclic option enabled:
(in this example is an image sequence of 11 frames with alpha channel)

[image]

Then add a Scene strip to the VSE, make it alpha over, and disable OpenGL preview in the Scene Preview/Render, so you get the image sequence from the compositor. The 11 frames will play repeatedly the duration of the scene strip.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

If you want rather simple movement you can keyframe image offset as indicated in the image above

If you wanted a more complex movement. I would place your images as texture on a plane in 3D View Orthogonal Camera.  Use [follow path] constraint and keyframes to achievement movement.  Render as PNG format again.  Use new images in VSE.  If need many images you render should be longer.

Blender VSE expects names such as x_001.png x_002.png for convenience. In case you need to change your names.

If the 20 images need to be repeated multiple times then I would simply copy and paste the strip multiple times. If you copy and paste once then 1->2 , copy and paste both and 2->4, so doubling each time.

Comment: you mean like moving text from left to right ? I have an animated picture that changes its shape from frame to frame.

Answer (score 1):

Work Fine 2.79 https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Sequencer/Loop_Media

"Pick a Scene, Image, or Movie strip in the Video Sequence Editor, and use the Strip menu to find the Loop Media operator. A speed effect strip will be created to accomplish the looping effect"

Good Script

Answer (score 0):

You can <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> the sequence once and then <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> as many times as you need.

Adjust your final frame and render.

Tested with image animations.